# How important is having an anti-reflection layer on a glass lens?

Tags: eye, optometry, sunlight, glasses

There are many factors that play a role when a person chooses their next pair of glasses. For example, I would think that the exact material of the lens would be of crucial importance. Yet, it looks like having/not having an anti-reflection layer is (at least marketed as) a crucial component for a decent pair of glasses.

I have had three pairs of glasses, one of which had the anti-reflection layer. I failed to notice any difference whatsoever. Now that I am buying my 4th pair, I would like to know:

How could we measure the difference between the lens with and without the anti-reflection layer? Are their any comparison studies/hard facts that an anti-reflection layer significantly improves the lens ability to convey light?

Related search on the [physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=anti-reflection). In particular, [this Q&A](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12208/how-come-an-anti-reflective-coating-makes-glass-more-transparent?newreg=6a9b8bc77d014e39bae7c1d74e75dff9) makes me believe that an anti-reflection layer makes sense only when the following is known:

- exact wavelength
- exact angle of incidence

Which makes me further doubt that anti-reflection layer is important.